# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Условно по сложности проектирования трубопроводы можно разделить на следующие группы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант без запятых.

По сложности проектирования трубопроводы можно условно разделить на следующие группы.

В исходной же фразе "условно" приходится трактовать как вводное слово (= "условно говоря,"), поскольку его нельзя однозначно отнести только к глаголу, и скорее всего, нужна запятая после этого слова.